# Using <a href="javascript:myFunction()"> to access a function in an external js file

Tags: javascript, html, self-invoking-function

When I include `myFunction()` within the same HTML page of `<a href="javascript:myFunction()">` the function is called fine upon click of the `a` tag.

But when `myFunction()` is located in an external JS file within a self invoking function, the function does not get called.

What format should the call be to access this function?

The external file looks like:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    function myFunction() {

    }
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you referenced your .js file? Something like: `<script src="quadrat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Yes the external js file is referenced at the bottom of the html page

Comment: Try referencing it inside the `<head>` tag of your html file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you want to call is a local function declared inside a [immediate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). You have no way to call it outside of it's scope.

If you can modify your external file, you could export the function on window object like this:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    window.myFunction = function() {

    }
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: I am able to edit the external file, so this solution works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to refer the .js in page like

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>

 (function (window, document, $, undefined) {
      window.myFunction = function() {

  }
  })(window, document, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is known just in its concept (`function (window, document, $, undefined)`).

You have several ways to export it:

a. export into variable:

```
myFunction = (function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    myFunction = function() {

    }
    return myFunction
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

b. export into window, or window.export, it depends which framework you are using. see: http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2011/08/21/javascript-modules/